# Dynamically-generated heatmap WMS tiles on GeoServer/Leaflet displays wrong

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms, tiles, heat-map

I am using a GeoServer to calculate dynamically a heatmap on points coming from a postgresdatabase with the SLD style presented there : https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html

However, if the result is okay in OpenLayer preview in GeoServer, the WMS tiles are totally wrecked when requesting them from Leaflet like here :

[image]

I kind of understood that the problem was due to tiles calculating only points in their tile, leading to this, and that single-tile mode was a solution.

However, while OpenLayers provides the possibility to request WMS in single tiled mode, Leaflet does not.

There are plugins developed here and there but I am working with VueJS so I can't use them directly.

As a consequence I am looking for a way in GeoServer to correct this behavior but i don't know if there is a way and how to do it. I tried to add tiled=false in parameters of the URL but it doesn't seem to work and the tile caching  tutorials are aimed at saving tiles which is different from what I want.

Comment: On GIS SE site coding questions should have relevant part of existing code included in the question, otherwise question is most likely to get closed.

Comment: WMS GetMap requests are stateless and when WMS server sends one image it has no idea about what sort of request is coming next. So I think there in no way to fix your problem on GeoServer side. Have you tried https://github.com/ptv-logistics/Leaflet.NonTiledLayer?